# Error in Approximation

Tags: real-analysis

I have to estimate the error in the approximation of $\left|\cos(x)- 1+\frac{x^2}2\right|$ $\lt \varepsilon$ when $|x| \lt 0.1$ using the series 
$$ \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dotsb $$
But it also says that I have to use Cauchy's Test which states 
$\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges when $\{a_n\}$ is positive and strictly decreasing and limit of $a_n$ equals 0. 
How should I approach this?
Thanks in advance